# Concise way to create "variants" of classes while still maintaining class hierarchy in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, dry

Say I have these classes:

```
interface X {
    public void setX(int x);
    public int getX();
    public void say();
}

interface Y extends X {
    public void shout();
}

class BaseX implements X {
    private int x;
    public BaseX(int x) {setX(x);}

    public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
    public int getX() {return x}

    public void say() {
        System.out.println(getX());
    }
}

class BaseY extends BaseX implements Y {
    private int y;
    public BaseY(int x) {super(x); setY(0);}
    public BaseY(int x, int y) {super(x); setY(y);}


    public void shout() {
        System.out.println(y + "!!");
    }
}
```

I want to extend `BaseX` and `BaseY` with new classes: `MyX` and `MyY`:

```
class MyX extends BaseX {
    public MyX(int x) {super(x);}

    @Override
    public void say() {super.say(); System.out.println("(MyX)");}
    public void printValue(int z) {
        System.out.println("value: " + z + " - x: " + getX());
    }
}
```

But here's the problem. What next? Do I extend `MyX` or `BaseY`? In this case
it seems that I need to extend both:

```
class MyY extends MyX, BaseY {
    // impossible. how to do this?
    public MyY(int x) { (MyX super)(x);}
    public MyY(int x, int y) { (BaseY super)(x, y);}

    @Override
    public void say() {(MyX super).say(); System.out.println("(MyY)");}
    @Override
    public void printValue(int z) {(MyX super).printValue(z); System.out.println("(MyY)");}
}
```

Then I would use `MyX` and `MyY` like so:

```
MyX mX = new MyX(1);
MyY mY = new MyY(2, 3);

assert mY instanceof MyX; // MyY is a subclass of MyX, so this works.
assert mX instanceof X; // BaseX implements `X`.
assert mY instanceof X; // ...so mY should too.

mX.setX(5);
mX.getX(); // 5
mX.say(); // 5 (MyX)
mX.printValue(10); // value: 10 - x: 5

mY.setX(15);
mY.getX(); // 15
mY.say(); // 15 (MyX) (MyY)
mY.printValue(10); // value: 10 - x: 15 (MyY)
// mY inherits from BaseY, so this works:
mY.shout(); // 15!!
```

I tried creating an interface that's all defaulted methods:

```
interface BaseXMethods extends X {
    public default void say() { System.out.println(getX()); }
}

interface BaseYMethods extends Y { ... }

class BaseX implements BaseXMethods {
    ...
}

class MyY extends MyX implements BaseYMethods { ... }
```

but I'd still need to implement the getters, setters, and constructors, which is tedious:

```
class BaseX implements BaseXMethods {
    private int x;
    public BaseX(int x) {setX(x); /* or maybe call an init method from superinterface */}

    public int getX() {return x;}
    public int setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
}

class BaseY extends BaseX implements BaseYMethods {
    private int y;
    public BaseY(int x) {super(x); setY(0);}
    public BaseY(int x, int y) {super(x); setY(y);}

    public int getY() {return y};
    public void setY(int y) {this.y = y;}
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This sort of question is usually easier to address for specific cases than in the abstract.  As a general recommendation, though: don't get yourself into that situation.  Favoring composition over inheritance can help, and it is an example of the more general strategy of keeping your inheritance tree shallow.  That can work together well with minimizing inheritance of implementation (inheritance of interface is less troublesome), and keeping your classes well focused.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Could you give an example? I thought composition could only be used with dynamically typed languages like JavaScript.

Comment: Suppose you're creating a fantasy role-playing game.  You have a class representing players' in-game avatars, maybe `Hero`.  Now suppose the hero may be armed with either a sword or a magic wand.  Do you create new subclasses `SwordWieldingHero` and `WandWieldingHero`?  No.  You create a `Weapon` interface, implemented by classes `Sword` and `Wand`, and you give `Hero` a member of type `Weapon`.  That -- especially the last part -- is composition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, ok. Don't see how it will help here though.

Comment: As I said, it is difficult to answer this sort of question in the abstract.  It's unclear how it makes sense to break down the problem.  Nevertheless, composition provides a very flexible tool for modulating the behavior of your classes.  It pairs well with generics, too.  It's not a solution in itself, but rather a mechanism that could support one, and more generally that can support keeping your inheritance trees shallow.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well basically I am making a game. The game has a client and server. Then I have some entities: `BaseEntity, BaseLivingEntity, BaseEntityPlayer`. The client extends those classes: `ClientEntity, ClientLivingEntity, ClientEntityPlayer` to provide things like methods to draw the entities on the screen. The server extends them too: `ServerEntity, ServerLivingEntity, ServerEntityPlayer` to add methods like, ex. `sendMovementToClient`. The `BaseEntity` class just provides basic things like `getX` and `getY`, which exist on both the client and server.